# how to access html element from abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple crud class like this with diverse methods:

```
export abstract class Crud<T extends { id?: number }> {}
```

In many of my components I then extend this class, f.e.:

```
export class CompanyComponent extends Crud<Company> implements OnInit {}
```

If I define a `ViewChild` in the `CompanyComponent`, how could I access it from the abstract class? I would like to append some classes to this element from the abstract class.

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible by definition: you'd need to add the ViewChild to the parent class, not the child. Out of curiosity, why use ViewChild to add classes?

Answer (score 0):

> If I define a ViewChild in the CompanyComponent, how could I access it from the abstract class? I would like to append some classes to this element from the abstract class.

Unsure if this is what you are looking for, how about doing something as below:

- Define an abstract field in the abstract class and use it within a method

```ts
    // Within abstract class
    abstract elementRef: ElementRef;
    
    addClass() {
        if (this.elementRef) {
            // Do something with elementRef
            const htmlElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
            htmlElement.className = "some-class";
        }
    }
```

- Get hold of the ElementRef, in the component extending the abstract class

```ts
    // Within CompanyComponent
    @ViewChild('someRef') elementRef!: ElementRef;  // someRef refers to template reference variable in html
```

Another way could be that the Component extending the abstract class calls a method implemented by Abstract class, passing it the `elementRef` as an argument.